# Installing programs in different Linux machines with very limited access

Tags: linux, static, installation, compilation, rpm

I have to log into Linux servers from different customers and use there essential tools like SVN, etc. Most of the times I get no root access, and usually the administrator is on holidays :) so I have to get the way to use this tools there. Sometimes this is very straightforward process, just compile the code. But in some of the cases, I have to get before a lot of different tools compiled before it, so I can easily spend two hours just to get SVN compiled.

I wonder what do you think is the best workaround or solution for this. I thought about the following:

1. There is somekind of tool that can convert a RPM (or DEB or similar) package to a static binary with all necessary libraries, etc, included there. Even if I get a very big file.
2. If I need to use program "X", I could create a script like call_X.sh that when invoked, uses SSH to send the input to the program "X" installed in some remote machine, do there the necessary operations, and get the resulting files back.

Comment: Do you only need SVN on these remote systems?

Comment: no, it depends on the situation. Usually SVN, sometimes GCC, sometimes even more ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rootless GoboLinux](http://www.gobolinux.org/?page=rootless) and [Gentoo Prefix](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/gentoo-alt/prefix/) are both systems in which packages can be installed to a local directory without root permissions.

It's also possible to extract the contents of a .deb (`dpkg -x`) or .rpm (`rpm2cpio | cpio -i`), and you may be able to use the results with little or no modifications, depending on how they were built.  [klik](http://klik.atekon.de/) actually automatically does this for some Debian packages.